# ORA-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I am passing ID's in oracle proc. ID's can be in 1000's. currently its able to process around 600 ID's, if I pass more than 600 ID's - I am getting ORA-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested. ID is varchar2 datatype, how can I process 1000's of Id's in varchar2 or what will be the best strategy to handle this kind of issue. Any guidance/suggestion  will be highly appreciated. Can this be solved  using CLOB datatype?

```html
//this is how I am processing Id's

create or replace procedure Emp(
emp_id in varchar2
)

//passing those id's in CTE before passing to subquery

WITH
EMP_LIST AS(
select regexp_substr(emp_id,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  connect by level <= LENGTH(regexp_substr(emp_id, '[^,]+'))+1
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a collection or `VARRAY` rather than passing a comma-delimited string:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0);
```

Then you can use it something like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE emp(
  emp_ids IN number_list
)
IS
BEGIN
  -- Do something with the ids like inserting them into a table
  INSERT INTO employees ( id )
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   TABLE( emp_ids );

  -- Or something like this:
  SELECT something
  INTO   some_variable  -- you need to define this variable first
  FROM   some_table
  WHERE  emp_id MEMBER OF emp_ids;
END;
/
```

---

## Update

If you can't create anything then you can use a built-in collection like `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE emp(
  emp_ids IN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
)
IS
BEGIN
  -- Do something with the ids like inserting them into a table
  INSERT INTO employees ( id )
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   TABLE( emp_ids );

  -- Or something like this:
  SELECT something
  INTO   some_variable  -- you need to define this variable first
  FROM   some_table
  WHERE  emp_id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( emp_ids ) );
END;
/
```

*(Note: `SYS.ODCI*LIST` types are `VARRAY` data types and do not support the `MEMBER OF` operator like collections do; instead you can get the values from the `VARRAY` using a nested `SELECT` statement with a `TABLE()` collection expression.)*

However, if you really can't `CREATE` anything then you won't be able to `CREATE PROCEDURE` .... not sure there is any solution to that apart from talking to your DBA.

Comment: @MTO thanks for your effort, I will try this in the morning and will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @MTO where do I use that create TYPE , in the database or java class? I dont' have privilege to create anything I can just read

Comment: @MTO I don't see sys.ODCINUMBERLIST , I can see other options like sys.odciconst and dump...

Comment: @david [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d1f48c3c9cc119266aaa62aa53f2ae7) works for me; maybe your DBA has locked it down.

Comment: @MTO its working perfect now, thank you very much for great helo.